# Elasticsearch not connecting from remote host

Tags: ubuntu, elasticsearch, ubuntu-16.04

I installed Elasticsearch v 5.1 on ubuntu 16.04 & it's up and runnging. I already update `network.host` through

`/etc/elasticsearch/elasticsearch.yml`.
When test own server by

`curl -XGET 'http://HOST_IP:9200'`

its response ok. But if I trying from another remote server then its says time out.
I want to connect this elasticsearch from a remote ip. I already tried

`ufw allow 9200/udp`

in host server.
What am I missing. Thanks.

Comment: @Andrew White can you plz check this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need different value for bind_host and publish_host, instead of using network.host. from Elastic docs:

> The network.host setting explained in Commonly used network settings is a shortcut which sets the bind host and the publish host at the same time. In advanced used cases, such as when running behind a proxy server, you may need to set these settings to different values

Check it out here: 
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-network.html#advanced-network-settings

Comment: so what are the values of `network.host`,`network.bind_host`,`network.publish_host` i.e with one is local/host ip and which one is remote ip?

Comment: network.bind_host is the local interface address, and publish_host is the remotely accessible address. That's written clearly in the link I pasted.